# Subset File based One Line and Printing Other lines Until it reaches next line

Tags: bash, perl

I have a text file that contains multiple entries that look like the sample below:

```
# 2018 11 21 17 47 37.708756 -34.390213 116.803673 2.6972 0.442474 3.324627 2.840390 0.885880 890
LM01 0.836408 1.00 P
LM01 1.035398 1.00 S
LM03 3.987074 1.00 S
# 2018 11 22 11 58 25.550581 -34.439400 116.750832 2.8513 0.288144 3.306790 2.576028 0.771026 891
LM01 1.664419 1.00 P
LM01 2.471786 1.00 S
LM03 3.536432 1.00 P
# 2018 11 22 14 38 7.190175 -34.447819 116.788727 3.1661 0.577347 2.063253 2.132511 0.608057 892
LM01 1.629825 1.00 P
LM02 3.059825 1.00 P
LM03 3.284825 1.00 P
LM01 2.378885 1.00 S
```

I need to come up with a way, preferably in Bash or Perl, that reads line with the `#`, subsets that line based on column 8 (latitude), and if the condition is met, prints the rest of the lines (e.g. LM...) until it reaches the next line with the `#`.  For example, I only want to print the 'entries' where column 8 < -34.4, and include the LM* lines for that entry.

I can come up with code to read each `#` line, but I'm unsure how to program "if condition is met, print LM lines until you reach the next # line".  The expected output would be:

```
# 2018 11 22 11 58 25.550581 -34.439400 116.750832 2.8513 0.288144 3.306790 2.576028 0.771026 891
LM01 1.664419 1.00 P
LM01 2.471786 1.00 S
LM03 3.536432 1.00 P
# 2018 11 22 14 38 7.190175 -34.447819 116.788727 3.1661 0.577347 2.063253 2.132511 0.608057 892
LM01 1.629825 1.00 P
LM02 3.059825 1.00 P
LM03 3.284825 1.00 P
LM01 2.378885 1.00 S
```

Comment: Would you please show the expected output based on the given sample?

Comment: Sure, I've provided the expected output above - subset based on column 8 in the # line being < -34.4.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `gawk` record separator, `perl` should have similar...

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)#' '$7<-34.4{printf "%s", rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

# 2018 11 22 11 58 25.550581 -34.439400 116.750832 2.8513 0.288144 3.306790 2.576028 0.771026 891
LM01 1.664419 1.00 P
LM01 2.471786 1.00 S
LM03 3.536432 1.00 P
# 2018 11 22 14 38 7.190175 -34.447819 116.788727 3.1661 0.577347 2.063253 2.132511 0.608057 892
LM01 1.629825 1.00 P
LM02 3.059825 1.00 P
LM03 3.284825 1.00 P
LM01 2.378885 1.00 S
```

note that you want `<` since the sign is negative.  Since we use `#` as the record delimiter, field number is one less.

We define the record separator as the leading # or after new line.  Normally RS is between records but here it's leading the records.  That's why we capture the matched record separator `RT` and assign to a variable to be used in the (next) record.  Also the RT includes the new line, that's why `printf` doesn't have one.

Comment: +1.  Thanks!  I was wondering if you could describe what this code is doing?  I'm fairly new to awk and hopefully this post could be useful for others.  With your above one-liner, is the record separator `RS='(^|\n)#'` splitting up the record, and then rest of the one-liner is describing the condition to print for each record?Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On lines not starting with `#` print if flag is on, otherwise set flag (and print) subject to a condition

```
perl -wlnE'
    if (/^\s*[^#]/) { say if $y } elsif ((split)[7] < -34.4) { $y=1, say }
' file
```

With the offered sample input in `file` this prints the expected output.

The flags `-lnE` can be `-ne` instead, with `print` instead of `say` in code. The `-w` is just for warnings, often omitted in one-liners (I always use it).  See [Command switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lane '$matches = ($F[7] < -34.4); print if ($matches .. (/^#/ and not $matches)) and ($matches or not /^#/)'
```

It's a bit involved. You can make `$matches` be any expression on the `# ...` lines that you want. `($matches .. (/^#/ and not $matches))` matches all header lines up to and including the next (potentially non-matching) header and then `and ($matches or not /^#/)` excludes any non-matching headers.

(The `..` is the [Range Operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) which was designed for exactly these use cases)

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl one-liner

```
  perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(^#.+?)(?=^#|\Z)/gsm ) { print $1 if (split(" ",$1))[7] < -34.4 } '
```

with Inputs

```
$ cat geeb.txt
# 2018 11 21 17 47 37.708756 -34.390213 116.803673 2.6972 0.442474 3.324627 2.840390 0.885880 890
LM01 0.836408 1.00 P
LM01 1.035398 1.00 S
LM03 3.987074 1.00 S
# 2018 11 22 11 58 25.550581 -34.439400 116.750832 2.8513 0.288144 3.306790 2.576028 0.771026 891
LM01 1.664419 1.00 P
LM01 2.471786 1.00 S
LM03 3.536432 1.00 P
# 2018 11 22 14 38 7.190175 -34.447819 116.788727 3.1661 0.577347 2.063253 2.132511 0.608057 892
LM01 1.629825 1.00 P
LM02 3.059825 1.00 P
LM03 3.284825 1.00 P
LM01 2.378885 1.00 S
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(^#.+?)(?=^#|\Z)/gsm ) { print $1 if (split(" ",$1))[7] < -34.4 } ' geeb.txt
# 2018 11 22 11 58 25.550581 -34.439400 116.750832 2.8513 0.288144 3.306790 2.576028 0.771026 891
LM01 1.664419 1.00 P
LM01 2.471786 1.00 S
LM03 3.536432 1.00 P
# 2018 11 22 14 38 7.190175 -34.447819 116.788727 3.1661 0.577347 2.063253 2.132511 0.608057 892
LM01 1.629825 1.00 P
LM02 3.059825 1.00 P
LM03 3.284825 1.00 P
LM01 2.378885 1.00 S
$
```

Comment: Nice :). Don't need quotes, just `print $1`.  Also I often find it clearer to drop at least some parens, up to `... if (split " ", $1)[7] < -34.4` (but these are preferences I guess)

Comment: Thanks @zdim. I shortened further..removed parens and used ````$&````..just updated it

Comment: OK, that's a valid and interesting use of `$&` but I am not sure that it is better than capturing explicitly (it can cause head-scratching, may be less efficient ... and possibly introduce bugs if things are changed in the future)?